# Is there a function in ms-access sql-query with which one can extract a certain string?

Tags: sql, string, ms-access, substring

I was wondering if there is a function in MS-Access SQL-Query with which one can extract a given string of each cell of a column (similar to `substring()` but with a string as criteria).

For example, I would like to extract the keywords SUN and FUN from the following column (named Lyrics)

**Lyrics**

```
AeSUN9SL
Pla4FUNP
L2wqSUNop
ASUNfdNNK
7dssFUN9SL
```

so that I am only left with:
**Lyrics**

```
SUN
FUN
SUN
SUN
FUN
```

in the column. Since the length as well as the number of "unused" characters before and after the string keyword differ,  I could not use `left()` and `right()`.

Is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: And if the string has both?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - This case luckly never occurs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression subtring function 
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_substr.php

```
select regexp_substr(Lyrics,'(SUN|FUN)', 1,1, 'i') from yourtablenamehere;
```

Comment: That would be exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately, this function dows not exist to my knowing in ms-access. I meanwhile updated the question - sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` and `like`:

```
select (case when lyrics like '%SUN%' then 'SUN'
             when lyrics like '%FUN%' then 'FUN'
        end)
```

In MS Access (which was not the original tag):

```
select iif(lyrics like '*SUN*', 'SUN'
           iif(lyrics like '*FUN*', 'FUN', NULL)
          )
```

You can also include this in an `UPDATE`:

```
update t
    set lyrics = iif(lyrics like '*SUN*', 'SUN'
                     iif(lyrics like '*FUN*', 'FUN', NULL)
                    ) ;
```